# How can I have two different "processes" for the same entity accessing the same outputs in VHDL?

Tags: process, entity, vhdl

I have an entity which looks at five pairs of switches and sets letters on a 7-segment display based on the state of those switches (`H` for `00`, `E` for `01`, `L` for `10` and, `O` for `11`).

I have a process in the architecture of this file which has a case statement that looks at the values of the switches and writes the proper letter to the corresponding display.

Now, I also have three switches that will, depending on their states, move the letters to adjacent 7-segment displays (like a rotation). I originally had this in another process within the same architecture, but I get compilation errors because I'm using the outputs (the 7-segment displays) in two different places.

I'm completely new to VHDL so this may seem simple, but how do I separate these two functions? Do they need to be in different files? How to have them both run "concurrently"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drive a signal from two different processes, the two drivers will "compete".

For `bit` and `std_ulogic` types, the compiler will complain that you are not allowed to have two drivers on a signal.  If you are using `std_logic` types, then there is a "resolution function" which decides what the resulting value is when you drive two different values onto a signal.  For example, if you drive a `0` and a `1`, you'll get  the defined-unknown result `X`.

It is possible to drive `Z` (high-impedance) onto a signal to allow another signal to override it, however, if you want to synthesise it you need to check what your tools will do with it as very few chips these days can actually have real high-impedance modes on their internal signals.

A portable, tidy, synthesisable way to achieve what you want is to treat a logic `1` as less-strong than a logic-`0`.  Then you can combine two separate signals with an AND gate:

```
process1: process 
begin
   sig1 <= '1'; -- not driving 
   -- some statemachine eventually does
     sig1 <= '0';
   -- and then 
     sig1 <= '1'; -- when it's finished
end process;

process2: process
begin
    sig2 <= '1'; -- not driving
       --- similarly...
       sig2 <= '0'; -- at some point
end process;

actual_sig <= sig1 and sig2;
```

If it makes more sense for your purposes for a `0` to be the 'idle' state, then use an 'or' instead to merge the signals together.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this  (Warning it hasn't been debugged, it analyzes and elaborates).

What this shows is that there are registers for the display digits and that rotation function  operates between the output of those registers and the driven display digit ports.

The rot_select could of course be separated from the write pointer.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;   -- TO_INTEGER

entity rot_digits is
    port (
    -- the 8 7-segment display with defaults for simulation visibility.
        dp0:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0000001"; -- 0
        dp1:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "1001111"; -- 1
        dp2:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0010010"; -- 2
        dp3:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0000110"; -- 3
        dp4:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "1001100"; -- 4
        dp5:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0100100"; -- 5
        dp6:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0100000"; -- 6
        dp7:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0001111"; -- 7
  -- rotation select, also used for write pointer
        rot_select: in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        wr_enab:    in  std_logic;
        reset:      in  std_logic;
        switch:     in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)  
    );
    type display8 is array (integer range 0 to 7) of 
            std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

    constant H:         std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "1001000"; -- H
    constant E:         std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0110000"; -- E
    constant L:         std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "1110001"; -- L
    constant O:         std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0000001"; -- O (0)
    constant ERR:       std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0110110"; -- error
    constant BLANK:     std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "1111111";       

end entity;

architecture foo of rot_digits is

    -- digit is (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)  6 downto 0, '0' for ON (sink)
    --    a
    --   f  b
    --    g
    --   e  c
    --    d

    -- (d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) are register values for stored digits
    signal d0:          std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
    signal d1:          std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
    signal d2:          std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
    signal d3:          std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
    signal d4:          std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
    signal d5:          std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);  
    signal d6:          std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
    signal d7:          std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);

    function "ror" (l: display8; r: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0))  
        return display8 is
        variable rot: integer range 0 to 7;
    begin
        if IS_X(TO_X01(r)) then   -- unknown defaults to 0 rotation
            rot := 0;
        else
            rot := to_integer(unsigned(r));
        end if;

        case rot is
            when 0 => return l;
            when 1 => return 
                display8'(l(0),l(7),l(6),l(5),L(4),l(3),l(2),l(1));
            when 2 => return 
                display8'(l(1),l(0),l(7),l(6),l(5),L(4),l(3),l(2));            
            when 3 => return 
                display8'(l(2),l(1),l(0),l(7),l(6),l(5),L(4),l(3));  
            when 4 => return 
                display8'(l(3),l(2),l(1),l(0),l(7),l(6),l(5),L(4));    
            when 5 => return 
                display8'(l(4),l(3),l(2),l(1),l(0),l(7),l(6),l(5)); 
            when 6 => return 
                display8'(l(5),l(4),l(3),l(2),l(1),l(0),l(7),l(6));   
            when 7 => return 
                display8'(l(6),l(5),l(4),l(3),l(2),l(1),l(0),l(7));
        end case;
    end function;

    signal selected:   std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);

begin

SEL:
    selected <= H    when switch = "00" else
                E    when switch = "01" else
                L    when switch = "10" else
                O    when switch = "11" else
                ERR;

ROTATE:
    (dp0,dp1,dp2,dp3,dp4,dp5,dp6,dp7) 
            <= display8'(d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) ror rot_select;

Display_Registers:
    process (wr_enab,reset, switch)
    begin
        if (reset = '1') then
            (d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) <= display8'(others => BLANK);
        elsif (wr_enab = '1') then
            case rot_select  is
                when "000" => d0 <= selected;
                when "001" => d1 <= selected;
                when "010" => d2 <= selected;
                when "011" => d3 <= selected;
                when "100" => d4 <= selected;
                when "101" => d5 <= selected;
                when "110" => d6 <= selected;
                when "111" => d7 <= selected;
                when others =>
                    (d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) <= display8'(others => ERR);
             end case;  


        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

The ERR assignments are to show there's an other than '0' or '1' either in the rot_select or switch vectors.  Should be three horizontal bars.

By definition there's an equivalent process for the concurrent signal assignment to the display digit output ports.  You could likewise have that process perform the rotations without a newly declared "ror" shift operator.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to focus more on solving your problem than answering your original question. For a good answer to your question, see Martin's (@martin-thompson) post.

The key to the presented solution is to generate an intermediary signal, which will hold the 'rotated' letters. In short:

- signal #1 <= an array of letters, without rotation, selected directly form your pairs of switches
- signal #2 <= an array of rotated letters; the amount of rotation comes from you 'rotation' switches

This way, we can have one process that generates signal #1, and another taht generates signal #2. It is usually better to structure your solution so that each signal is assigned from within a single process.

The code below should solve your problem:

```
entity switches_to_7seg is
    port (
        -- each switch pair selects one letter from 'H', 'E', 'L', 'O'
        switch_pair_0: in bit_vector(1 downto 0);
        switch_pair_1: in bit_vector(1 downto 0);
        switch_pair_2: in bit_vector(1 downto 0);
        switch_pair_3: in bit_vector(1 downto 0);
        switch_pair_4: in bit_vector(1 downto 0);
        -- the rotation switches select the amount of rotation from 0 to 4
        rotate_switches: in bit_vector(2 downto 0);
        -- the outputs are five 7-segment displays
        lcd_display_0: out bit_vector(6 downto 0);
        lcd_display_1: out bit_vector(6 downto 0);
        lcd_display_2: out bit_vector(6 downto 0);
        lcd_display_3: out bit_vector(6 downto 0);
        lcd_display_4: out bit_vector(6 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture dataflow of switches_to_7seg is

    -- declare an enumerated type to make it easier working with the output letters
    type output_letter_type is ('H', 'E', 'L', 'O');
    type output_letter_vector_type is array (natural range <>) of output_letter_type;

    -- this comes directly from the switches
    signal switch_selected_letters: output_letter_vector_type(0 to 4);
    -- this is an intermediary signal, with the letters rotated
    signal rotated_letters: output_letter_vector_type(0 to 4);

    -- return a letter corresponding to the state of a pair of switches
    function output_letter_from_bit_vector(bits: bit_vector) return output_letter_type is
    begin
        case bits is
        when "00" => return 'H';
        when "01" => return 'E';
        when "10" => return 'L';
        when "11" => return 'O';
        end case;
    end;

    -- return a value for driving a 7-segment display to show the corresponding letter
    function seven_seg_from_output_letter(letter: output_letter_type) return bit_vector is
    begin
        case letter is
        when 'H' => return "0110111";
        when 'E' => return "1001111";
        when 'L' => return "0001110";
        when 'O' => return "1111110";
        end case;
    end;

begin

    -- this first part reads the input switches and convert them to letters
    switch_selected_letters(0) <= output_letter_from_bit_vector(switch_pair_0);
    switch_selected_letters(1) <= output_letter_from_bit_vector(switch_pair_1);
    switch_selected_letters(2) <= output_letter_from_bit_vector(switch_pair_2);
    switch_selected_letters(3) <= output_letter_from_bit_vector(switch_pair_3);
    switch_selected_letters(4) <= output_letter_from_bit_vector(switch_pair_4);

    -- this first process generates the intermediary signal 'rotated_letters'
    rotate_letters: process (all) begin
        case rotate_switches is
        when "000" =>
            rotated_letters <= switch_selected_letters;
        when "001" =>
            rotated_letters <= switch_selected_letters(1 to 4) & switch_selected_letters(0);
        when "010" =>
            rotated_letters <= switch_selected_letters(2 to 4) & switch_selected_letters(0 to 1);
        when "011" =>
            rotated_letters <= switch_selected_letters(3 to 4) & switch_selected_letters(0 to 2);
        when "100" =>
            rotated_letters <= switch_selected_letters(4) & switch_selected_letters(0 to 3);
        when others =>
            rotated_letters <= switch_selected_letters;
        end case;
    end process;

    -- this second process outputs the rotated letters to the displays
    output_letters: process (all) begin
        lcd_display_0 <= seven_seg_from_output_letter( rotated_letters(0) );
        lcd_display_1 <= seven_seg_from_output_letter( rotated_letters(1) );
        lcd_display_2 <= seven_seg_from_output_letter( rotated_letters(2) );
        lcd_display_3 <= seven_seg_from_output_letter( rotated_letters(3) );
        lcd_display_4 <= seven_seg_from_output_letter( rotated_letters(4) );
    end process;

end;
```